# Gradient descent for periodic function

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Problem:

minimize E=$\sum_{t=0}^T [ Y(t)-\sum_{k=0}^K(X(t+k)*cos(k*F+PHI)) ]^2$

where F, PHI - has to be optimized;

Y(t), X(t) 1D arrays are given;

t=0...T; T=1000;

k=0..K; K=10;

I can use FFT and get direct estimation of F and PHi (and it works fine), but my question is: are there other methods which can work in time domain using iterative approach?
I tried to use mini-batch gradient descent, but because the problem has a lot of local minimums, it rarely converges (and strongly depend on initialization).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: My main point is that

it's possible to rewrite this as a sum $\sum\limits_{i}g_{i}(F,\phi)$.
(with possibly a very large number of terms)
where, each of these functions has a Lipschitz continuous derivative. This essentially comes from the fact that $\cos$ and it's derivatives are bounded, and the fact that the parameters only interact through linear combinations. That means you can apply gradient descent with a constant step size.

For details, see p.144 at http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~vishy/introml/notes/Optimization.pdf

In any case, that is just show it's possible to design an algorithm which is guaranteed to reach some local minimum, but it depends on where you start.

Comment: Can you clarify how can I set G=k*F+PHI? cos(k∗F+PHI) is function of k, so if I replace argument by "G" then it becomes cos(G) - it is just a number. Or do you mean G(k)=k*F+PHI?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you clarify how can I set G=k*F+PHI? cos(k∗F+PHI) is function of k, so if I replace argument by "G" then it becomes cos(G) - it is just a number (there is no "k" anymore).     Or do you mean G(k)=k*F+PHI? And in this case cos(G(k)) - is still function of k, but I will need to estimate G(k), where k=0...10, so I need to estimate 10 more parameters.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking there was only one k.

Comment: I tried mini-batch gradient descent using derivatives ("E" by "F" and "E" by "PHI"). But this approach stuck in local minimum.
I wonder how your approach is better (it looks like it also can stuck in local minimum)?

Comment: I tested your approach with replacing G=k*F+PHI, and as expected it can stuck in local minimum. Do you have any suggestions about converting the problem into constraint optimization? For example I know that F belongs to range 0...K/2, and PHi belongs to range 0...K/2.

Comment: Yea I'm not surprised it got stuck in a local minima. That is the nature of this method. The algorithms that I'm aware of that are guaranteed to find glboal optima assume that the function is convex over the whole domain, which your function is not, due to the trig functions. Out of curiosity, how does the local minimum compare with the result of your spectral method? This constrained/global optimization

Comment: I'm not too familiar with constrained optimization, but if you know that K and Phi lie in a certain box then the following should work: Discretize the region $(0, K/2) \times (0, K/2)$ and attempt the gradient descent procedure at each grid point. If the grid is fine enough then one of the points should be in the basin of attraction of the global minimum.